# My table only updates after two clicks on commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My code is almost done, im only stopped at this bug. Every thing looks correct to me, but it needs 2 clicks to show the table properly, im new on Primefaces and not very good on the frontEnd part.

The 'update' property of p:commandButton should update the table, but it only does it on the 2nd click. I've tried "update=@this", "update=:form:tbl2", ":form"
PD: The backend part is good, since the table is loaded correctly, but not shown on the frontend.

```
<p:commandButton class="options" ajax="true" actionListener="#{ajustesHistBean.cargarDatos()}"  value="Consultar" oncomplete="dataTableWidgetVar.filter()" update="tbl2" >
</p:commandButton>
...
<p:dataTable id="tbl2" widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar" value="#{ajustesHistBean.datos}" var="e" scrollable="true" filteredValue="#{ajustesHistBean.datosFiltrados}">

<p:column filterBy="#{e.cuenta}" headerText="Cuenta" filterMatchMode="contains">
<h:outputText value="#{e.cuenta}"/>
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

... Java: ...

```
public void cargarDatos() {
        DAO dao = new DAO();
        setDatos(dao.listarAjusteHist(this.selectedFecha, this.selectedVersion));
        setDatosFiltrados(this.datos);             
    }
```

Im looking for it to update the table on the first click.

Comment: Why are you using `ajax="false"`?

Comment: It doesnt change a thing, on true happens the samething, i will update the code on question.

Comment: then, don't update the table AND filter, use either one but not both

Comment: also, probably your filter data is not processed at the moment of filtering.. but that's just guessing for us as you did not provide a [mcve].

Comment: So, the error is on: filteredValue="#{ajustesHistBean.datosFiltrados}" . If i delete this, it works fine (on 1 click) but, the filter doesnt work of course. Am i missing some property so it can work properly? Do i have to do something else on the cargarDatos() method?

Comment: [mcve] please as requested

Comment: I think you need to look after action execution ordre to understand why it doesn't work Good luck

Comment: And btw, what is your PF version? Old I assume since you do a `widgetVar.filter()` instead of a `PF('widgetVar').filter()`